# Angular2 Global Data Model?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

There are several questions and discussions about Angular2 using global variables and global states, but my particular needs slightly more than this and I am struggling for the best way to approach it (mainly due to conflicting information, published at different times during the angular2 release cycle).

So here it goes, I am in essence creating a SPA (Single page application) to work as an order input screen for a sales office.

I have a structure a bit like this:

```
 |_main_order_entry controller.ts
     |__order_line_controller.ts
        |_product_controller.ts
        |_colour_controller.ts
        |_size_cotroller.ts
        |_promotion_controller.ts
        |_comments_controller.ts
```

So when you load the **main_order_entry_controller.ts**, you it pre_populates some basic data, next order number in sequence, and order date/time, easy stuff.

Then we start with an **order_line_controller**, where things get a bit tricky, lets say

1. **product_controller**, is a dropdown box, you select a product
      It then populates the colour controller view with available colours
      for the chosen product
2. Once you choose a colour it populates the size controller with the
      sizes available in the colour and product selection, if you change
      either of these options, the other drop down boxes update with the 
      new data returned by the REST API.
3. Once you have completed one **order_line_controller** instance, it automatically inserts a whole new instance of the **order_line_controller**, as the number of potential orderlines is limitless.

Now at any time if any of the dropdown boxes are changed, the REST api will be re-called and the valid options will be updated.

For this to work, I need a clean way to store all the data whilst the user loads the **main_order_entry_controller.ts**

Now my thinking is the best way to do this would be create two models

```
main_order_model.ts
order_line_model.ts
```

Then create a service, each time the **main_order_entry_controller.ts** is loaded, it creates a new instance of *main_order_model.ts*, and then for each **order_line_controller** that is loaded, it creates a new instance of *order_line_model.ts*

Giving me a service with a data structure a bit like this:

```
{
  "orderdate": "01/01/2017",
  "orderef": "JHASGAZXC",
  "orderlines": [
    {
      "linenumber": "1",
      "product": "T-SHIRT",
      "colour": "BROWN",
      "size": "Large",
      "promotion": "True",
      "comments": "Customer has requested gift wrapping"
    },
    {
      "linenumber": "2",
      "product": "JEANS",
      "colour": "BLUE",
      "size": "X-SMALL",
      "promotion": "False",
      "comments": "None"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then each time a controller value is changed, it updates the data model in the global service, then each controller in theory could pull any data it needed from the service.

Im fairly new to Angular2 so I am looking for correct **Angular2** way to do this, I have been asking around on the official gitter channel this week and not had much luck, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

To manage the global state you can use ngrx/store along with ngrx/effects. Those two implements the Redux pattern, that's a great way to manage the state of the app, so you can have a single source of truth to store your data and share it across all the life time of your app.

First try to learn the redux pattern. Then to learn ngrx go to https://github.com/ngrx/store . If you need to ask something you can go to https://gitter.im/ngrx/store

Comment: Thank you very much, I will add an answer in when I have written code to reflect my question to show a working answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.